# How to test utility function which creates a file

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a small utility function I am trying to test with Jest and Enzyme. I'm getting nowhere.

```
function downloadCSV(csv: string, filename: string) {
  let csvFile;
  let downloadLink;

  csvFile = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });
  downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadLink.download = filename;
  downloadLink.href =window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
  downloadLink.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

My test so far:

```
import downloadCSV from './downloadCSV';
let myReader = new FileReader();

describe('downloadCSV utility', () => {

  it('should create a file of CSV type', () => {
    window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();
    const actual = downloadCSV('foo,bar', 'my-filename');
    console.log(myReader.readAsText(actual));  // logs undefined
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a TypeScript solution, it's not related to React and enzyme. You can test this function using only jestjs and TypeScript.

To translate to JavaScript, remove the types from the function signature (everything after the `:` for each argument), and in the tests make the following substitutions: `(global as any)` for `global`, `window.URL.createObjectURL as jest.MockedFunction<typeof window.URL.createObjectURL>)` for `window.URL.createObjectURL`, and replace all references to `.ts` with `.js`.

`downloadCSV.ts`:

```js
export function downloadCSV(csv: string, filename: string) {
  let csvFile;
  let downloadLink;

  csvFile = new Blob([csv], { type: 'text/csv' });
  downloadLink = document.createElement('a');
  downloadLink.download = filename;
  downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(csvFile);
  downloadLink.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  downloadLink.click();
}
```

`downloadCSV.spec.ts`:

```js
import { downloadCSV } from './downloadCSV';

(global as any).Blob = jest.fn();
window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn();

describe('downloadCSV', () => {
  const csv = 'csv';
  const filename = 'filename';

  it('should create a file of CSV type', () => {
    (global as any).Blob.mockReturnValueOnce('mocked blob');
    const anchorMocked = { href: '', click: jest.fn(), download: '', style: { display: '' } } as any;
    const createElementSpyOn = jest.spyOn(document, 'createElement').mockReturnValueOnce(anchorMocked);
    document.body.appendChild = jest.fn();
    (window.URL.createObjectURL as jest.MockedFunction<typeof window.URL.createObjectURL>).mockReturnValueOnce(
      'https://github.com/mrdulin'
    );

    downloadCSV(csv, filename);

    expect(createElementSpyOn).toBeCalledWith('a');
    expect(document.body.appendChild).toBeCalledWith(anchorMocked);
    expect(anchorMocked.click).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(anchorMocked.href).toBe('https://github.com/mrdulin');
    expect(anchorMocked.download).toBe('filename');
    expect(anchorMocked.style.display).toBe('none');
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
PASS  src/stackoverflow/57810999/downloadCSV.spec.ts
  downloadCSV
    ✓ should create a file of CSV type (7ms)

----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File            |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files       |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 downloadCSV.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.161s
```

The completed TypeScript demo is [here](https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57810999).